# Getting an attribute error when working with function in Python

Tags: python, function, class

I browsed through several similar questions on here before I decided to ask. There were similar questions about the same error, but they weren't the same type of problem, and none of the answers resolved my problem.

Nonetheless, I'm getting a Typeerror which says 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'. Here is my code:

```
def Rectangle(width, height):
  area = Rectangle[width] * Rectangle[height]

a = Rectangle(5, 7)
print(a.area)
```

Now I know there are easier ways to do this, but the challenge is to do it using functions and classes. I'm wondering where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: I think you want a class, not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [`class`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). I'll get you started:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.height
```

---

What you currently have is a function. But seeing as each instance of your object should have it's own attributes, you need to create a type to store them.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. What does the atproperty do?

Comment: @HunterWatkins Seeing as area is calculated depending on width and height, we don't want to have it as a constant value. The `@property` allows us to access it as normal while still keeping it proportional to its other attributes.

Comment: Wow, that's useful! Thanks so much. I literally had the first 2 lines of your code written before I posted this, because I figured I had to use a class, but I swore I could do it with just a function. But I was wrong. Thanks again for your help! @AlexThornton